# Find gradient of a equi-angular spiral (log spiral)

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I encountered a problem in determining the gradient in cartesian coordinates (x,y) of a logarithmic spiral (or equi-angular spiral) profile. The log-spiral definintion is as shown below (similar to a previous question of mine):

[image]

I have also generated several points in accordance to the profile using the equation `r=a*e^(θtan m):

Point x y

0 9.9999997 2.700000258

1 9.805274245   2.030963458

2 9.452271678   1.338905277

3 8.921115486   0.654692774

4 8.196483978   0.016283107

5 7.269524783   -0.531552828

6 6.139893897   -0.937932945

7 4.817842108   -1.147059284

8 3.326250384   -1.099962912

9 1.702494595   -0.736840057

10 0 0

with (xc,yc) = (7.699656589, 4.680792423); a = 2.013727242; and m = 30 degrees

The plot of the points:

[image]

Using cartesian equation from the book: https://books.google.com.sg/books?id=YlLpO8Sv8RMC&pg=PA69&lpg=PA69&dq=log+spiral+cartesian+equation&source=bl&ots=FsW4lA8Y_K&sig=KRAOE42VVGMeTLHiCRlVNhnK6dY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=rjErVdWWLYaKuASO6oCYBw&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAzgK#v=onepage&q=log%20spiral%20cartesian%20equation&f=false

The cartesian equation of a log spiral is (excerpt of the book):

[image]

What I then did next was to bring the term `y/x` to the left hand side of the equation so that the cartesian equation equates to zero.

I substituted the points into the equation but they did not yield zero for any case:

Point Equation_value

0 -1.423441983

1 -1.421707215

2 -1.449201544

3 -1.52278722

4 -1.677072486

5 -1.997427817

6 -2.770942087

7 -5.989331442

8 10.18165028

9 1.961047581

10 -27.63998102

This didnt make sense to me and I'm not sure what I did wrong. Formula in Excel appears to be correct though.

Also, does anyone has an approach/equation describing the gradient of a logspiral curve, given (x,y) coordinates?

Thank you.

Regards
Corse

Comment: The confusion is $a$ in the google book is in the constant deciding rate of rise or decay, whereas $a$  of your formula is coefficient of the exponential expression itself. I would recommend you visit differential relation derivation $ \dfrac{dr}{d\theta} = a r $ before plunging in with so much computational labor.

Comment: can i derive the cartesian dy/dx from dr/d(theta) ?

Answer (score 0):

Hope the graph and given spiral equation would clarify. Else, meet in chat.

$$ r = a e^{ \cot m . \theta }$$
[image: LogSpiral]

Comment: what are the axes? r, th?

Answer (score 0):

As shown in your book excerpt, some problems are just not served very well by Cartesian coordinates. Let's consider this problem in complex coordinates. The generic form for a logarithmic spiral with flair coefficient $b$ and its gradient are given by

$$z=e^{(b+i)\theta}\\
\dot z=(b+i)e^{(b+i)\theta}$$

If you want the gradient expressed as the tangent angle, then

$$\Theta=\text{tan}^{-1}\frac{\mathfrak{Im}(\dot z)}{\mathfrak{Re}(\dot z)}$$

Of course this can expressed in term of $x$ and $y$, but it's very messy, indeed.